# Use of unassigned local variable (Very simple function with a string array). C# language

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I looked previous questions but it didn't help.
I have a very simple function written in c#.
It give me compiler error "Use of unassigned local variable 'linea' " (line (2)).
What could be wrong? And could tell me how to correct it please?

```
    public void llenarTabla()
    {

        int idx;
        string[] linea; (1)
        for (idx = 0; idx < numListas; idx++)
        {
            linea[0] = Convert.ToString(idx); // (2)
            switch(OrdenListas[idx]){
                case 0: linea[1] = "Crescente"; break;
                case 1: linea[1] = "Decrescente"; break;
                case 2: linea[1] = "Aleatorio"; break;
                default: linea[1] = "No especificado" ; break;
            }
            linea[2] = Convert.ToString(LongitudListas[idx]);
        }
    }
```

I already saw the reference "Compiler error if a variable is used but it might be not initialized. But as far I see the variable string[] (indexes:0,1,2) is inizialized in every case except numlistas = 0 (numlistas is a class parameter and its value is supposed to be >=1).

I also tried to change line (1) and (2) to:

```
(1) List<string> linea;

(2) linea.Add(Convert.ToString(idx));
```

but same error (when I tried to change line (1) and (2) I put as a comment all the following lines.

Thank you in advance for every help

Comment: Would you mind marking one of the answers as accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do:

```
string[] linea = new string[3];//3 is the length of your array
//you can store 3 elements in linea [0] [1] and [2]
```

See [MSDN reference for arrays in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You have declared a variable of type `string[]` (array of string), but you have not assigned it a value. In other words, the `linea` variable is not yet initialized when you use it.

Your line (1) needs to look like:

```
string [] linea = new string[numListas];
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you declared the variable `string[] linea` but you never initialized it to a specific value before using it within the body of the `for` loop.  Based on the usage within the loop you want it to have 3 elements so the following will work

```
string[] linea = new string[3];
```

Answer (score 1):

Change to this:

```
  public void llenarTabla()
    {

        int idx;
        List<string> linea=new List<string>();
        for (idx = 0; idx < numListas; idx++)
        {
            linea.Add(Convert.ToString(idx)); // (2)
            switch(OrdenListas[idx]){
                case 0: linea.Add("Crescente"); break;
                case 1:linea.Add("Decrescente"); break;
                case 2: linea.Add("Aleatorio"); break;
                default:linea.Add("No especificado" ); break;
            }
           linea.Add(Convert.ToString(LongitudListas[idx]));
        }
    }
```